# php table exporting it to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

ok so i have this code for a table.

```
$idUser = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = "SELECT b.*, c.name FROM bookings b JOIN user c ON b.userId=c.userId WHERE b.date >=CURDATE() and isdelete=0";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</a></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['start'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
        if($row['isPayed']==0){
          echo '<td>Blom Lunas</td>';
        }
        else{
          echo '<td>Sudah Lunas</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<tr><td colspan="6">No data in table</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

how can i import this table into excel when i click a button bellow the table.

Comment: thx @RST good find

Answer (score 0):

Best option is exporting selected data to csv file, not drawing table. Something like that:

```
$filename = 'data.csv';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array_od_data = [
        $row['id'],
        $row['date'],
        $row['start'],
        $row['name'],
        $row['isPayed'] == 0 ? 'Blom Lunas' : 'Sudah Lunas'
    ];
    $line = implode(',', $array_od_data) . '\r\n';
    file_put_contents($filenae, $line, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Then simply import `data.csv` file into Excel sheet